# How to remove duplicate substrings from an undelimited string in perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have an odd situation where I want to remove all but the first match of a substring inside of a very long undelimited string.  I have found some similar topics here, but none quite like mine.

For simplicities sake, here are some sudo before and after strings.
I have an undelimited file where "c" could be thousands of random characters but "bbb" is a unique string:

```
aaabbbbbbccccccbbbccccccbbbccccccaaa
```

I want to remove all but the first bbb:

```
aaabbbccccccccccccccccccaaa
```

Also, I would like to be able to use this as a perl script I can pipe through:

```
cat file.in | something | perl -pe 's/bbb//g' | somethingelse > file.out
```

But, unlike my example above, I want to leave the first occurrence of "bbb" intact."

This seems like it should be fairly easy, but it is stumping me.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $string = 'aaabbbbbbccccccbbbccccccbbbccccccaaa'; 
my $seen; 
sub first { 
  $seen++; 
  return $_[0] if $seen eq 1; 
  return '';
} 
$string =~ s/(bbb)/first($1)/ge;
say $string;
```

Outputs:

> aaabbbccccccccccccccccccaaa

Comment: +1: elegant. The oneliner: `echo "aaabbbbbbccccccbbbccccccbbbccccccaaa" | perl -pe '$seen=0; sub f{return $seen++ == 1 ? shift : ""} s/(bbb)/f($1)/ge'`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'aaabbbbbbccccccbbbccccccbbbccccccaaa';
$string =~ s/(?<=bbb).*?\Kbbb//g;
print $string;
```

Output:

```
aaabbbccccccccccccccccccaaa
```

Comment: When I tried this I got something like: Unrecognized escape \K passed through.

Comment: @Raven - The zero-width assertion `\K` (`K`eep the stuff on the left) started with Perl v5.10.  If it's unrecognized, it's likely your version of Perl is earlier than v5.10.

Comment: That explains it.  We are still running SuSE 10 on many of our servers which by default is only Perl v5.8.8.  That is unfortunate as your solution appears smaller and more efficient than the other.

Comment: @Raven - Instead of using `\K`, a capture can be used: `s/(?<=bbb)(.*?)bbb/$1/g`.